# Execute particular component after click on md dialog button

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have 8 graph images on left side panel of the page. When I'm dragging these images and dropping on right side panel then i'm displaying MD Dialog box. In md dialog box i'm displaying list in drop down menu.

[image]

I referred [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456564/angular-2-call-existing-component-from-another-component)

After selection of item from drop down list then i'm clicking on "Yes" button of md dialog box.

On this button click I want to execute particular component based on item selection. For example, If I select "Heap Memory" then I want to execute "HeapMemoryComponent" and etc.

routing.ts

```
import  {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HeapMemoryComponent} from './aem-down-time-graph/aem-down-time-graph.component'
const appRoutes:Routes = [
{
 path: 'abc',
 component: HeapMemoryComponent
}
];
export const routing:ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

LeftPanelComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {LeftpanelService} from "../leftpanel.service"
import {Leftpanel} from "../leftpanel";
import {MdDialog} from "@angular/material";
import {MdDialogRef} from "@angular/material";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {ServersListDialogComponent} from "../servers-list-dialog/servers-list-dialog.component";
@Component({
selector: 'app-leftpanel',
templateUrl: './leftpanel.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./leftpanel.component.css']
})
export class LeftpanelComponent implements OnInit {
 dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ServersListDialogComponent>;
 leftpanels:Leftpanel[];
 receivedData:Array<any> = [];

 constructor(
   public dialog: MdDialog,private service:LeftpanelService,public router:Router
 ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.service.getLeftpanels().subscribe(lst =>this.leftpanels=lst);
 }

 transferDataSuccess($event) {
 this.receivedData.push($event.dragData);
 this.openDialog();
 }
 openDialog() {
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ServersListDialogComponent, {
    disableClose: false
  });

  this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('result: ' + result);
    this.dialogRef = null;
    if(result.componentName == "HeapMemoryComponent"){
      this.router.navigate(['HeapMemoryComponent']);
    }
  });
 }

}
```

After click on "Yes" I want to execute like following component based on item selection.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-mainpanel',
 templateUrl: './heap-memory.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['heap-memory.component.css']
})
export class  HeapMemoryComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() {
 console.log("HeapMemoryComponent object is created...");
}

ngOnInit() {
 console.log("HeapMemoryComponent ....");
}

}
```

Above HeapMemoryComponent have some html response and this above component will have service. And I will have multiple component like above.

I didn't get how to execute like above particular component?
Please give me solution

Comment: Do you mean navigate to a particular component?

Comment: @echonax. yes, I want to navigate particular component based on item selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to navigate to a particular component after the dialog result, you can do something like this:

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
...
constructor(public router:Router..){}

this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('result: ' + result);
    this.dialogRef = null;
    //based on result
    if(result.componentName == "HeapMemoryComponent"){
      this.router.navigate(['abc']);
    }
  });
```

Note that I've made up the `result.componentName` part, I don't know what result you get in the callback.

Comment: Thank you, @echonax. I'm getting "Cannot find name 'Router'" error.

Comment: @AnilJagtap hmm did you add `router:Router` like I did in the `constructor`?

Comment: I added in constructor.

Comment: @AnilJagtap oh I guess you didn't import the `Router`. Updated my answer.

Comment: I imported above library. Getting following error: "Duplicate identifier 'Promise'" and "Cannot find name 'Router'". What I missed?

Comment: @AnilJagtap which version of angular2 are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.1 version of angular 2.

Comment: @AnilJagtap can you add the imports part to your question as well? So that we can see the whole picture.

Comment: I added imports parts in my post.

Comment: @AnilJagtap I don't see the `import {Router} from "@angular/router";` as I've written in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, @echonax. I did spell mistake. I'm getting following error when I'm calling component in afterClosed() method Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'HeapMemoryComponent'. What I need to do this?

Comment: @AnilJagtap can you add your routing module to your question please?

Comment: I added routing.ts file

Comment: @AnilJagtap if path is `abc` then navigation needs to be `this.router.navigate(['abc']);`

Comment: @AnilJagtap Glad I could help ;-)

Comment: I added HeapMemoryComponent in module.ts file. This component its executing after when I'm secting itme in dialog box. But, when app is loading that time HeapMemoryComponent is executing. I want to stop it. How?

Comment: @AnilJagtap ehm I didn't quite understand the issue. Can you open a new question for it? (I assume this question is resolved)

Comment: sure. I will open new question.

Comment: I opened new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809220/how-to-prevent-angular-2-component-execution